# Does the Vorlon's real appearance actually match the encounter suit they use?

Tags: babylon-5

In the last episode of season 4 (The Deconstruction of Falling Stars) the story jumps forward a million years and shows an evolved human in an encounter suit.

> The head of the encounter suit is very similar to a human's head. Would it be correct to suppose that the head of the Vorlon's encounter suit is also similar to a Vorlon's real head before they evolved?

[image]

Comment: I don't think any of this is particularly spoiler-ish.

Comment: Well. I think that that episode is very spoilerish. IMO.

Comment: Given that we see at least one other "evolved" human much earlier in the show (one Mr Jason Ironheart) the fact that humans go on to become an elder race is really not at all a spoiler.

Comment: Allow me to disagree. It isnt the same that one human "evolved" than all the race "evolved".
Apart that this removed almost all the interest in the series, if you know how it ends.

Comment: Spoilers are things that are revealed and that 'spoil' things that are intended to be hidden from view. Since the entire episode is about a human a million years from the current date, it's not in the least bit spoiler-y to learn that they've evolved. Note also that his jumping into an encounter suit isn't integral to any part of the plotline.

Comment: For the record, putting the entire question into spoiler tags is a colossally bad idea.

Comment: >! Dont you think that it spoiled the Vorlon's real shape. Because they are using a very similar encounter suit.

Comment: @Valorum. You are right. ^^U

Comment: For the record, spoiler tags don't work in comments.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to know that I am making a fool of myself. :P

Answer (score 3):

No.

There is an episode, "Falling Towards Apotheosis," also in season 4, where

> the Vorlon's true appearance is actually depicted, and they are clearly 
>  not bipedal at all, with no obviously discernable head.

See [the Vorlon's true form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9ioF.jpg).

Comment: >! I am not sure that that was their original shape.

>! Almost all the 'ascended' beings (Lorien, Vorlons, humans) looked similar. As spheres of energy with tentacles if they needed to attack or grab anything.

Comment: Suggest then you might want to edit your question to make it clear you're asking about their look prior to becoming fully evolved.

Comment: However, also not all of them look that way, since the Shadows do not.

Comment: I was only asking about the Vorlons. The Shadows dont use an encounter suit, and I am not sure that they have ascended in beings of pure energy as the Vorlons.

Comment: @Spkit2000 Had the Vorlons become "pure energy"? If so, how could Kosh be "poisoned" in the pilot episode?

Answer (score 3):

No, the suit is merely to hide their true form which appears more ethereal. Each race views them differently. This was explained in the episode where Kosh saved Sheriden from falling from the transport car. Each race views a Vorlon as a deity from their planet's culture.

Further infomation can be found here - https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Vorlon

Answer (score 2):

Encounter suits are *supposed* to be for *practical* reasons - to allow a being to live in an environment in which it could not ordinarily survive. However, the Vorlons wore encounter suits for a different reason - to *conceal their true appearance*. Of course, they had conditioned all races to see them differently, so arguably they were concealing that deception rather than their "true" appearance; still, Kosh was able to leave his encounter suit and rescue Sheridan proving that he didn't need it to survive. He was weakened after this, not because of the exposure to the environment, but supposedly because so many people had seen him.

The purpose of the Vorlon's suit to deceive would suggest then that it was nothing at all like their "true" appearance. But are we talking their true appearance *now*, or before they "ascended"? The screenshot in another answer possibly shows their current form without any manipulation, but that might not be what they *originally* looked like. The human encounter suit that you have drawn a comparison to looks a little like human features *now*, but what does an ascended human look like? Perhaps the idea of an encounter suit for an ascended human is to make their appearance more like their ancestors.